# C++ create thread function with params results in converting errors

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am doing my first steps in C++ multi threading and ran into a problem.
What I wouyld like to achieve is set out tasks with parameters that will be running in separate threads.
Googling for answers did not bring me the answer.

The system I am using consists of Windows 10 Pro, and Code::Blocks 20.3 with MinGW 17.1

I have created a simple example to get a feeling for it.
The first example (a single cpp file) works just fine.
The second however (in a class) has build errors even though I am using the same code.

I hope someone can explain the reasons why, and hopefully shows me how to solve thsi.

First (working) example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

struct Param
{
    std::string param1;
};
unsigned Counter;

unsigned __stdcall DoSomething( void *ptr )
{
    std::cout << "In second thread...\n";

    Param *p_tmp = reinterpret_cast<Param*>(ptr);
    Param p_param = *p_tmp;
    std::string result = p_param.param1;

    while ( Counter < 1000 )
    {
        Counter++;
        std::cout << result << Counter << '\r';
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2));
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    _endthreadex( 0 );

    return 0;
}

void CreateThread()
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    unsigned threadID;
    std::string result{"Count: "};
    Param param;
    param.param1 = "Count: ";

    std::cout << "Main thread\nCreating second thread...\n";

    // Create the second thread.
    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &DoSomething, (void*)&param, 0, &threadID );

    // Wait until second thread terminates
    WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );

    std::cout << "Returned to Main thread\nCounter should be 1000; it is-> "<< Counter << std::endl;
    // Destroy the thread object.
    CloseHandle( hThread );
}

int main()
{
   CreateThread();
}
```

The second example (in a class):

```
struct Param
{
    std::string param1;
};
unsigned Counter;

void CthreadFrame::CreateThread()
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    unsigned threadID;
    Param param;
    param.param1 = "Count: ";

    std::cout << "Main thread\nCreating second thread...\n";

    // Create the second thread
    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &DoSomething, (void*)&param, 0, &threadID );
    // Wait for second thread to terminate
    WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );

    std::cout << "Returned to Main thread\nCounter should be 1000; it is-> "<< Counter << std::endl;
    // Destroy the thread object.
    CloseHandle( hThread );

/* End of void CreateThread */
}

unsigned __stdcall CthreadFrame::DoSomething(void *ptr)
{
    std::cout << "In second thread...\n";

    Param *p_tmp = reinterpret_cast<Param*>(ptr);
    Param p_param = *p_tmp;
    std::string result = p_param.param1;

    while ( Counter < 1000 )
    {
        Counter++;
        std::cout << result << Counter << '\r';
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2));
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    _endthreadex( 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

Build Messages:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Cthread (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Cthread\CthreadMain.cpp||In member function 'void CthreadFrame::CreateThread()':|
F:\Data\__C++\wxApps\Cthread\CthreadMain.cpp|114|error: cannot convert 'unsigned int (CthreadFrame::*)(void*)' to '_beginthreadex_proc_type' {aka 'unsigned int (*)(void*)'}|
f:\sdks\mingw-17.1\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\process.h|37|note:   initializing argument 3 of 'uintptr_t _beginthreadex(void*, unsigned int, _beginthreadex_proc_type, void*, unsigned int, unsigned int*)'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Use `std::thread`. Do not use `__stdcall`, `_beginthread`, `HANDLE` and other such nonsense. `#include <thread>` provides `std::thread` and associated facilities.

Comment: Declare your `CthreadFrame::DoSomething` as static function.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Georgy Firsov.

I would never have thought searching for std::msm_fn without your help.

I changed my code to:

```
std::thread th(std::mem_fn(&CthreadFrame::DoSomething), std::ref(*this), (void *)&param );
th.join();
```

And that did the trick. Now I can pass all sorts of variables to a thread function.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your thread function as static function:

```cpp
class CthreadFrame
{
public:
    void Start() {
        m_hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(
            nullptr, 0, &CthreadFrame::DoSomething, 
            this /* store params here */, 0, &m_uThreadId
        );
    }

private:
    static unsigned __stdcall DoSomething(void*);

private:
    HANDLE m_hThread;
    unsigned m_uThreadId;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. std::thraed results in error: "static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues". The static declaraion results in "error: cannot declare member function 'static unsigned int CthreadFrame::DoSomething(void*)' to have static linkage [-fpermissive]|"

Comment: @Ruud my answer mentioned `_beginthreadex` as a way to start new thread. If you want to use `std::thread` you may declare `DoSomething` as non-static and use `std::mem_fn` to pass it into `std::thread` : `std::thread th(std::mem_fn(&CthreadFrame::DoSomething), std::ref(*this), /* necessary params */);`